# how to insert multiple fields data in one column in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, loops

I have a form consist of multiple checkbox and input fields, I want to insert that data into a single column of a table, here is my form:

```
 <div id="container">
        <h1>property Detail</h1>
    <form action="" method="post">
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td> 
    Possesion
    <input type="checkbox" name="feature[]" value="possesion">
    </td>
    <td> 
    Possesion1
    <input type="checkbox" name="feature" value="possesion1">
    </td>
    <td> 
    Possesion2
    <input type="checkbox" name="feature" value="possesion2">
    </td>
    <td> 
    Possesion3
    <input type="checkbox" name="feature" value="possesion3">
    </td>
    <td> 
    Possesion4
    <input type="checkbox" name="feature" value="possesion4">
    </td>
    </td>
    </tr>

    <tr> 
    <td> <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </form>

    </div>
```

here is my controller:

```
 function index(){
            $this->load->view('form');

            if($_POST){


            $data_feature  = array (
           'feature' => $_POST['feature']
             );

            $data['var']= $this->Mdata->p_detail($data_feature);
            }   

        }
```

and here is my model:

```
   function p_detail($data_feature){
             $this->db->insert('feature',$data_feature);
             return $this->db->insert_id();


}
```

I am getting only one feature value in my table, I want to get all the values of check boxes which user checked.

Regards

Comment: first of all change `name="feature"` to `name="feature[]"` for all check box elements and then pass that value to controller. and after that `implode()` function to convert the array values to string and save as comma separated value in your database table field. hope it helps!!!

Comment: how to convert array values to string

Comment: type that exact sentence in google and also see my comment :)

Comment: @Harris Khan save values in `json` string in database in a single column.

Comment: if you want to save as json then use `json_encode()` as suggested

Comment: @HarrisKhan if solution is working for you . Then you may vote up so that it help others for the similar problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way to save it is json_encode to make the data in json string.There are many methods to save data like this:

Firstly correct the html to make all same name fields as array like:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="feature[]" value="possesion">
```

Method 1:

Make your data as json string to save:

```
$this->db->insert('feature',json_encode($data));//data is an array need to insert()
```

Method 2:

Make your data as serialize array:

```
$this->db->insert('feature',serialize($data));
```

Method 3:

Make your data array as string:

```
$this->db->insert('feature',implode(",",$data));
```

And if you want to row by row insertion then iterate posted values over loop like below:

```
function index(){

            $this->load->view('form');

            if($_POST){

                $data_feature  = $_POST['feature'];

                $data = [];
                foreach($data_feature as $f_key => $f_value){

                    $data[$f_key]['var']= $this->Mdata->p_detail($f_value);

                }

            }   

        }
```

And your modal use as;

```
function p_detail($data_feature){

             $this->db->insert('feature',$data_feature);//inserts into a single column 
             return $this->db->insert_id();//returns last inserted id

}
```

Comment: i want to insert it in rows instead of comma separated ??

Comment: so you want to insert each value in the seperate row?

Answer (score 0):

In view change all `name="feature"` to `name="feature[]"`.

Best way is save values in column as `json` string.Like below.

**Controller:**

```
function index(){
            $this->load->view('form');

            if($_POST){
            $features = $_POST['feature'];//array of features
            $json = json_encode($features);//json string you need to save it in database
            $data['var']= $this->Mdata->p_detail($json);
            }   

        }
```

And

**Model**:

```
  function p_detail($data_feature){
             $data = array('feature'=>$data_feature);//sets json string value to feature column
             $this->db->insert('feature',$feature);//inserts into a single column 
             return $this->db->insert_id();//returns last inserted id

}
```

> You need to use `json_decode()` for getting these values in `array` from
>   database.

Comment: features are inserting in one column by comma separated

Comment: this string is json string saved in table column.

Comment: Guys, I have a serious problem here too. I want to insert 3 values from three different 'selects' into a single database column. I have tried this method but wasnt fruitful. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

like what other people have suggested, change name="feature" to name="feature[]"

 if you want to insert the values of $_POST['feature'] to multiple rows in your table, you could loop inserting

```
$feature_array = $_POST['feature'];
$feature_len = count($feature_array);
for ($i=0;$i<$feature_len;$i++) {
    p_detail($feature_array[$i]);
}

function p_detail($data_feature) {
    $this->db->insert('feature',$data_feature);
    return $this->db->insert_id();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You comment in **Sagar Arora** solution is that you want to insert it in rows instead of comma separated.
For that, at first you have to change all checkboxs name from name="feature" to name="feature[]"

then  in you model

```
$this->db->insert_batch('feature', $data_feature['feature']);
```

Answer (score 0):

**you have a big problem in your application design** , if you Continue with this idea
 i think , you will have another problem in update and delete methods.

i advice you to create a **feature** table that can manage all your feature in your back office application and create intermediate table **property_feature** . because here you have many to many relationship between **feature** and **property** tables