# how to insert multiple fields data in one column through loop in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, loops

I have a form consist of multiple checkbox and input fields, I want to insert that data into a single column of a table in rows, here is my form:

```
<div id="container">
        <h1>property Detail</h1>
    <form action="" method="post">
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td> 
    Possesion
    <input type="checkbox" name="feature[]" value="possesion">
    </td>
    <td> 
    Possesion1
    <input type="checkbox" name="feature[]" value="possesion1">
    </td>
    <td> 
    Possesion2
    <input type="checkbox" name="feature[]" value="possesion2">
    </td>
    <td> 
    Possesion3
    <input type="checkbox" name="feature[]" value="possesion3">
    </td>
    <td> 
    Possesion4
    <input type="checkbox" name="feature[]" value="possesion4">
    </td>
    </td>
    </tr>

    <tr> 
    <td> <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </form>

    </div>
```

here is my controller:

```
 function index(){
            $this->load->view('form');

            if($_POST){

             $feature = $_POST['feature'];
             $features = json_encode($feature);

            } 
           $this->Mdata->p_detail($features);  
    }
```

and here is my model:

```
function p_detail($features){
        $this->db->insert('feature',$features);
    }
```

It will be through loop but I do not know how to exactly do this?? anyone please help me out.

Regards

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: what are you getting in `$features` in `p_detail` method and what exactly is your question here ? It stores all value in json format.

Comment: yes it stores all the value and insert into table, but i want to insert in rows instead of one row separated by comma

Comment: use `json_decode` and use loop to insert

Comment: i know it will be through loop but how to do i dont know

Comment: what is your column name ?

Comment: feature is my column name

Comment: and table name is also `feature` ?

Comment: yes table name is also feature

Comment: make the column type text and store the json in one column, no loop required if using json

Comment: if you want to loop through, do not use json_encode

Comment: you have asked the same thing in here: <br>
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42525186/how-to-insert-multiple-fields-data-in-one-column-in-codeigniter/42526738

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$feature_list = $_POST['feature[]'];
```

that's get list of file checkbox.

```
function p_detail($feature_list){
   $data=array();
     foreach($feature_list as $item){
       array_push($data,
          array('feature'=>$item));
      } 
       return $this->db->insert_batch('feature',$data);
    }
```

I hope so worked for you.

Comment: when checkbox not checked,dont return any value.be carefull

Comment: undefined index feature[]

Comment: change it to ```name="feature"``` for all inputs.
and ```$feature_list = $_POST['feature'];```